# Formal definition of measure (topological approach): unique extension of lipshitz function

Tags: probability, measure-theory, solution-verification

I am self-studying Todd Kemp's [probability course](http://www.math.ucsd.edu/%7Etkemp/280A/#syllabus). Instead of the the [unintuitive approach](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/34007/demystifying-the-caratheodory-approach-to-measurability) usually given to turn the Caratheodory outer measure into a proper measure, he uses a topological approach (i.e. considers the pseudo-metric, show that the pre-measure is a Lipschitz function, extend the pre-measure to the closure). Crucially, we require that a $K$-Lipschitz function on $V \subset X$ can be uniquely extended to $\overline{V}$. This was left as homework. Given the importance of the claim, I want to make sure that my proof is correct.

**Claim:** Let $(X, d)$ be a pseudo-metric space. Let $V \subseteq X$ be a nonempty subset, and suppose $f: V \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a Lipschitz function Prove that there is a unique extension $\bar{f}$ of $f$ to $\overline{V}$ that is also Lipschitz (with the same constant $K$).

*Proof.* We define an extension $\bar{f}$ of $f$ to $\overline{V}$ which is $K$-Lipschitz and then show that it is unique.

For $v \in V$, let $\bar{f}(v) = f(v)$. For $v \in \overline{V}$, let $\{v_i\}$ where each $v_i \in V$ be a sequence which converges to $v$. Define $\bar{f}(v) = \lim f(v_i)$. First show that $\bar{f}(v)$ exists. For every $\epsilon > 0$, find an index $N$ such that for every $i \geq N$, $|\bar{f}(v_i) - \bar{f}(v)| < \epsilon$. To this end, let $N$ be the index such that for all $n \geq N$, $d(v_n, v) < \frac{\epsilon}{2K}$. Then $|\bar{f}(v_n) - \bar{f}(v)| = \lim_{i \geq n} |f(v_n) - f(v_i)|$. Since

$$|f(v_n) - f(v_i)| \leq Kd(v_n, v_i) \leq K\left(d(v_n, v) + d(v_{i}, v)\right) < \epsilon,$$
$\bar{f}(v)$ exists. To see that $\bar{f}(v)$ is well-defined, consider two sequences $\{v_i\}$ and $\{v_i'\}$ both of whose limits are $v$. Then for any $\epsilon > 0$ we can show that $\lim_{i \rightarrow \infty} f(v_i) - \lim_{j \rightarrow \infty} f(v_j') < \epsilon$ by choosing a sufficiently large index $N$ such that for $i \geq N$, $d(v_i, v) < \epsilon/2K$ and $d(v_i', v) < \epsilon/2K$. Then
$$|f(v_i) - f(v_i')| \leq Kd(v_i, v_i') \leq K(d(v_i, v) + d(v, v_i')) < \epsilon.$$
Next we show that $\bar{f}$ is $K$-Lipschitz by considering $u, v \in \overline{V}$ and letting $\{u_i\}$ and $\{v_i\}$ be sequences of elements in $V$ whose limits are $u$ and $v$ respectively. We will show that $|\bar{f}(u) - \bar{f}(v)| \leq Kd(u,v) + \epsilon$ for any $\epsilon > 0$. Let $p, q$ be indices such that for all $i \geq p$ and $j \geq q$, $d(u_i, u) < \epsilon/2K$ and $d(v_j, v) < \epsilon/2K$. Then
$$|f(u_i) - f(v_j)| \leq Kd(u_i, v_j) \leq Kd(u,v) + K\left(d(u_i, u) + d(v_j, v)\right) < Kd(u,v) + \epsilon.$$
Thus $|\bar{f}(u) - \bar{f}(v)| = |\lim f(u_i) - \lim f(v_j)| < Kd(u,v) + \epsilon$.

Finally, to show that $\bar{f}$ is unique, consider some other extension $\bar{g}: \overline{V} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ of $f$ which is also $K$-Lipschitz and let $v \in \overline{V}$ with $\{v_i\} \rightarrow v$. If $v \in V$ then $\bar{f}(v) = \bar{g}(v)$. Otherwise for some $N$ such that for all $i \geq N$, $d(v_i, v) < \epsilon/K$, we have
$$|\bar{f}(v_i) - \bar{g}(v)| = |\bar{g}(v_i) - \bar{g}(v)| \leq Kd(v_i, v) < \epsilon.$$
By taking the limit as $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$, we have $\bar{f}(v) = \bar{g}(v)$ as well.

I also feel that the proof has room for improvement (there are four almost equivalent chunks) so suggest to this end are welcome.